# Proving second differences

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have this problem.
If $y=2x^3-x^2+3x+1$
Calculate the values of y corresponding to $x=0,1,2,3,4,5$ and form the table of forward differences.
Prove theoretically that the second differences $12x+10$  and verify this numerically.

(So the issue is not making the forward differences table it's the part with proving. How should I go about this? I can post a picture of the table if needed.

Comment: I think the theoretical proof asked for is the algebra that leads to that formula. So go ahead and calculate the forward difference table starting from $x$ rather than from $1$ or $2$ or $5$.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first differences by simplifying the following, which is the general formula for the $x^{th}$ first difference:

$2(x+1)^3 - (x+1)^2 + 3(x+1)+1 - (2x^3 - x^2 + 3x+1)$

Basically, get the  $(x+1)^{th}$ value of y and subtract the  $x^{th}$ value of y.

This gives you $6x^2+4x+4$

Repeating this process to find the $x^{th}$ second differences, meaning simplifying the following

$6(x+1)^2+4(x+1)+4-(6x^2+4x+4)$

gives you the solution. (Note: I'd prefer to use n instead of x, but you used x in your question so I stuck with that.)

Comment: Thanks alot this really helped.